# Insert data on SQL starting a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to add an entry in the database so that an user can create its user with the right role. How do I do it so that Spring inserts this data in the database when it's creating.

I read somewhere that I had to put a data.sql file in the resources folder with the insert but it didn't work as I expected.

```
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (1,'ADMIN');
```

The row isn't inserted. I had to manually insert the line in the database while the app was running.

**EDIT** This is my **application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_equipos
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=somepassword
logging.level.org.apache.commons.dbcp2= DEBUG  

spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, active from user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
```

Comment: data.sql should work. Can you provide more details about DB  you are using and what appication.proprieties you specified?

Comment: Ok I added the detail.

Comment: "it didn't work" is too vague, please show the error you get (or state explicitly that there is no error). And did the data.sql go in src/main/resources?  Please be explicit.

Comment: The row wasn't inserted.

Comment: I didn't try h2 (never used that syntax before).

Comment: you can use liquibase too